# Apply constraints to type based on the key-value of another type

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, extends

I have this basic type def:

```
export interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    created: Date;
    ...
}
```

The data with this type comes from a json file.
JSON.parse does not produce `Date` from string, so I was thinking to use the 2nd "reviver" parameter which allows you to modify the value that is being parsed based on the key.

So first I create a list of props that need to be modified:

```
const deserializeMap: Mapper = {
    created: v => new Date(v)
}
```

But I am not sure how to define the "Mapper" type.

it should be something like this:

```
type Mapper = {
    <K extends keyof Person >K: (value: any) => Person [K]
};
```

so depending on what property I define, the value returned by the function has to match the type of the property from the Person class

Comment: Should the deserializeMap contain no-ops for the properties that don't need modification? Or should it really be like `Partial<Mapper>`?

Comment: yes it's partial because right now only dates need to be created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to define the mapper type:

```
type Mapper = {
    [K in keyof Person]: (value: any) => Person[K];
};
```

and then you can say that your deserializeMap satisfies a `Partial<Mapper>`:

```
const deserializeMap = {
    created: v => new Date(v)
} satisfies Partial<Mapper>;
```

Depending on how you use deserializeMap, you may want to use a type annotation instead:

```
const deserializeMap: Partial<Mapper> = {
    created: v => new Date(v)
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgBTQGcIk4BvAWACg464lMBbYALjiJimQHMBuGvTiYebBgFcmAIzQDa9bFGCZUAE3YARFcDkBfGjRgBPMHgCymMKahwAvBUH0A2gGlEZANbAjEdAWKkALrsABQAbpgANuJimEhGAJR2AHz+UCRIroF6cjTYpJxwqsBEaAhRCABewBZgdg7ydIrKauxhKQzAAO5wWqjhCTS6HCoIROgIJQSYsOWRADy11sl8QA)

Comment: thanks! would it be possible to make `Person` a variable somehow, so it could be used with any other type?

Comment: @Alex Yep, just make `Mapper` generic: https://tsplay.dev/WJAogm